# getting product ID undefined

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to get product details and it came from backend but after sometimes when I refresh it is showing product ID as `undefined`. I don't know why it is `undefined` after getting the product and ID.

```
import { Layout } from "antd";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  //use effect
  useEffect(() => {
    if (params?.slug) getProduct();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [params?.slug]);
  //get product
  const getProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/pp/product/get-product/${params.slug}`
      );
      setProduct(data?.product);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <img
            src={`/api/pp/product/productPhoto/${product._id}`}
            width={"300"}
            height={"250"}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <h1>product details</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

I am trying to get product detail based on selected ID.

It has been successfully fetched but after refreshing it becomes `undefined` ??

Comment: Is the API returning valid data? This would be my first debugging step.

Comment: Yes I am getting data from backend,but when shown on UI when I refreshing ...it goes undefined.....first time data showing but after refreshing why not showing ???

Comment: Is the error undefined, or does it have a different value?

Comment: Lets assume you get the data you want from your api call. There is still the issue with persisting the data between page reloads. The `useState` hook is not a persistent storage. If you want to persist your data between page reloads you should have a look into `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` or a library like `Redux` and `Mobx`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to how you handle the initial render after refreshing.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      if (params?.slug) {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(
            `/api/pp/product/get-product/${params.slug}`
          );
          setProduct(data?.product);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    };

    getProduct();
  }, [params?.slug]);
```

Try fetching the product details on every render. The usage of async/await may cause the `undefined` error.

---

Always render the product only when it has been fetched and updated in the `state`.

```
{product && (
   <>
     <div className="col-md-6">
        <img
           src={`/api/pp/product/productPhoto/${product._id}`}
           width={"300"}
           height={"250"}
        />
     </div>
     <div className="col-md-6">
        <h1>product details</h1>
     </div>
   </>
)}
```